# PHP: Can't edit data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm going to build a mini system with login,add,edit,delete function. Login, add and delete was functioning without a problem but not on Edit. This is my update.php code. FYI, this code doesn't have any error displayed.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once "conn.php";

$conn=connect();
$db=connectdb();

$ic= "";
$parcelno = "";
$items = "";
if(isset($_REQUEST['ic'])){ $ic= $_REQUEST['ic']; }
if(isset($_REQUEST['parcel'])){ $parcel = $_REQUEST['parcel']; }
if(isset($_REQUEST['items'])){ $items = $_REQUEST['items']; }


mysqli_select_db($conn, $db) or die (mysqli_error($conn)."\n");
$sql="UPDATE parcel SET parcelno='".$parcel."', items='".$items."' where ic='".$ic."'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn)."\n");

}
```

Comment: ok then what? whats the question?

Comment: @avisheks cant update data from ysql database, whats wrong with my update.php code??

Comment: How do you mean by not updating? Is it end up with any error? Try printing the raw query?

Comment: @avisheks no error, but after clicking submit button on update page, the data is not updated in mysql database

Comment: get the raw query and put it directly to the database thorough some mysql client[phpmyadmin/mysql]

Comment: Try `print_r $result`. Maybe the query doesn't satisfy the `WHERE` condition of the update, so it may be updating nothing. That won't give an error because it simply did not see anything to update or rather, it update 0 things. The `print_r` will give you more info about `$result` so you will see its content.

Comment: Better still, try `mysqli_affected_rows()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't update data from MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091448/cant-update-data-from-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

your code didn't show errors, but it won't work..
you should define tables' and columns' names in your DB & your form fields' names as well..
In your code, they aren't clear (sometimes you are using `parcel` and sometimes `parcelno` as variables, those two are different. Both variables **MUST** match)
Now, let's consider you have a form where the user inserts new values to update the table in the database, after including the *connections.php*...

1. table name: `tname`
2. form fields: `Ic` `Parcel` `Items`
3. table columns: `ic` `parcel` `items`

When the user click *Save*:

```
    if(isset($_POST['Save']))
    {
        $ic= $_POST['ic'];
        $parcel= $_POST['parcel'];
        $items= $_POST['items'];

    $query= "UPDATE tname SET Ic='{$ic}', Parcel='{$parcel}', Items='{$items}'", 
    $res= mysql_query($query);
    if (!$res){echo mysql_error()};
    }
```

you can then return `$res` and display the fields updated.
This is the code for updating in MySQL.

But it is better to use `mysqli_affected_rows()`.